# How do I separate 2 variables to be independent from each other in the equation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I have an equation namely

```
(-1)*(1/(t*T))*Exp[-d*T + r*t1 - t*td]*
(a - b*p)*(c*((Exp[d*T + t*t1] - Exp[d*t1 + t*td]))*t - 
Exp[d*T + t*td]*(h + t*(o + p)) + 
Exp[d*t1 + t*td]*t*(o + p - T*s + s*t1) + 
Exp[d*T + t*t1]*h*(1 + t*td)) == 0
```

I would like to separate `t1` and `T`. That is lhs of the equations is in terms of variable of `t1` and other variables except `T` and rhs is in  terms of variable `T` and others variable except `t1`.

How can I do that by programming?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to express $t1=t1(T,...)$ and vice versa using the same equation?

Comment: No i would like to have F(t1,..) = G(T,...) the lhs has no T and  rhs has no t1, this means F is a function of t1 and others except T and G is the function of T and others except t1

Comment: What functions are you talking about? In your question there is one equation connecting the two parameters `t1, T` . You can solve the equation with respect to one or the other parameter, i.e. express $t1=t1(T,...)$ and $T=T(t1,...)$.